# make graphs bigger in astsa ARIMA graphs

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am currently learning how to deal with times series data and just found out about the **astsa library**.

The graphs generated by that package come in really handy but are very squeezed such that they aren't a good visualization to interpret. It would really help to allow the graphs to have some more space. Anyone knows how I can increase the size of the output of the acf2() and sarima() function?

```
library(astsa)
# Generate 100 observations from the AR(1) model
x <- arima.sim(model = list(order = c(1, 0, 0), ar = .9), n = 100) 

# Plot the generated data 
plot(x)

# Plot the sample P/ACF pair
acf2(x)

# Fit an AR(1) to the data and examine the t-table
sarima(x, p=1,d=0,q=0)
```

Comment: Have you tried simply increasing the height and width of the plots when saving? If that's not satisfactory, then perhaps what you want is to separate the two pieces of `acf2` into separate files? Currently your question is unclear.

Comment: thank you @JuliusVainora. That would have been a solution, too. I also just found another one which is increasing the size of the output field with setting options such that the field is larger

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved by increasing the size of the R output field via:

````
```{r set-options, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
options(width = SOME-REALLY-BIG-VALUE)
# your code
```
````